# How to deal with NAT python socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, nat

I am trying to make an application which is accessible for a wide range of users.
Its some basic socket + python networking stuff. 
I researched a bit recently and I tried a few things. 
I implemented some UPNP stuff via miniupnpc but the thing is that you need a permission to use UPNP on most routers which is not ideal for my needs. I am trying to completely bypass things like port forwarding. 
I also tried to completely switch from Python socket to pyp2p but I could't get it working because of the lack of documentation and maintenance on the project.

Is there an easy way to bypass NAT and if yes how ?

Client:

```
import socket
import struct
import os
import pickle
from pygame import mixer


def connect(host, port):
    ourmusic = []
    fileBRAIN = []
    musicPath = './music'

   s = socket.socket()
   print('created socket')
   s.connect((host,port))
   print('conected to ',host)

   #identify self
   hostname = socket.gethostname()    
   IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)    
   IPAddrBYTE = str(IPAddr).encode('utf-8')
   send_msg(s, IPAddrBYTE)

   if os.path.exists(str(host)) == True :
        print('server seen previously')

        #load host's song list
        fileBRAIN = pickle.load(open( str(host), 'rb'))

        #recieve new files from host
        receiveFiles(s, fileBRAIN)

        #compare files
        saveMusicList(ourmusic, musicPath)
        filesToTransmit = diff(ourmusic, fileBRAIN)

        #transmit music which host dont have
        transmitFiles(s , filesToTransmit, fileBRAIN)

        #save host's song list
        pickle.dump(fileBRAIN, open(str(host), 'wb'))

        #start playing music
        clientMainLoop(s)

else: 
        print('server not seen previously')

        #recieve music files from host
        receiveFiles(s, fileBRAIN)

        #compare files
        saveMusicList(ourmusic, musicPath)
        filesToTransmit = diff(ourmusic, fileBRAIN)

        #transmit music which host dont have
        transmitFiles(s , filesToTransmit, fileBRAIN)

        #save host's song list
        pickle.dump(fileBRAIN, open(str(host), 'wb'))

        #start playing music
        clientMainLoop(s)

def clientMainLoop(socket):
    mixer.init()
    while True:
        randomsongBYTE = recv_msg(socket)
        randomsong = randomsongBYTE.decode('utf-8')


        mixer.music.load('./music/' + randomsong)
        mixer.music.play()
        print('now playing: ' + randomsong)

        while mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
           temp = 0
        else:
            print('music ended receiving next...')

    def transmitFiles(socket, files, fileBRAIN):
          Transmissions = struct.pack('i',len(files))
          send_msg(socket, Transmissions) 

          for x in files:
                filename = str(x).encode('utf-8') 
                send_msg(socket, filename)

                file = open('./music/' + x , 'rb')
                file_data = file.read()
                send_msg(socket, file_data) 

                fileBRAIN.append(str(x))
                print(x + '\n' + 'has been send transmitted successfully')
                print('')

  def receiveFiles(s, fileBRAIN):            
       i = 1

    transmissionsDATA = recv_msg(s) 
    transmissionsTUP = struct.unpack('i',transmissionsDATA)
    transmissions = transmissionsTUP[0]
    print('there are ' + str(transmissions) + ' awaiting  receive 
         transmissions')

while i <= transmissions:
    BYTEfilename = recv_msg(s)
    filename = BYTEfilename.decode('utf-8')

    file = open('./music/' + filename, 'wb')
    file_data = recv_msg(s) 
    file.write(file_data)
    file.close()

    fileBRAIN.append(str(filename))
    print('transmission ' + str(i) + ' recieived')
    i = i + 1


def saveMusicList(musiclist, musicPath):
    for entry in os.listdir(musicPath):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(musicPath, entry)):
                    musiclist.append(entry)

#find elements which are not in the other list                        
def diff(li1, li2): 
     return (list(set(li1) - set(li2)))         

#TCP msg protocoll

def send_msg(sock, msg):
    # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recv_msg(sock):
    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
       return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    # Read the message data
    return recvall(sock, msglen)

def recvall(sock, n):
    # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data
```

Server :

```
import socket
import os
import struct
import pickle
import miniupnpc
from random import randint
from pygame import mixer



def init(port):
    fileBRAIN = []
    ourmusic = []        
    files = []
    musicPath = './music'

    try:
            #Network Gateway (port forwarding)
            upnp = miniupnpc.UPnP()

            upnp.discoverdelay = 10
            upnp.discover()

            upnp.selectigd()

            upnp.addportmapping(port, 'TCP', upnp.lanaddr, port, 
            'OpenMCS', '')

    except:
            print('INFO:Port is already forwarded or you dont have the 
            premission to forward it')



    s = socket.socket()
    host = ('') #socket.gethostname()
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)
    print(host)
    print('waiting for any incoming conections ... ')

    conn,addr = s.accept()

    #get client identity
    ClientIPAddrBYTE = recv_msg(conn)
    ClientIPAddr = ClientIPAddrBYTE.decode('utf-8')

    if os.path.exists(ClientIPAddr) == True :
            print('client seen previously')

            #load client's song list
            fileBRAIN = pickle.load(open( ClientIPAddr, 'rb'))

            #compare files
            saveMusicList(ourmusic, musicPath)
            filesToTransmit = diff(ourmusic, fileBRAIN)

            #transmit new files client doesn't have
            transmitFiles(conn, filesToTransmit, fileBRAIN)

            #recieve music files we dont have
            receiveFiles(conn, fileBRAIN)

            #save client's song list
            pickle.dump(fileBRAIN, open(ClientIPAddr, 'wb'))

            #start playing music
            serverMainLoop(conn, ourmusic, musicPath)

    else: 
            print('client not seen previously')

            #transmit own music files to client
            transmitFiles(conn, files, fileBRAIN)

            #recieve music files we dont have
            receiveFiles(conn, fileBRAIN)

            #save client's song list
            pickle.dump(fileBRAIN, open(ClientIPAddr, 'wb'))

            #start playing music
            serverMainLoop(conn, ourmusic, musicPath)


    def serverMainLoop(socket, ourmusic, musicPath):
         saveMusicList(ourmusic, musicPath)
         mixer.init()
         while True:
            randomsong = ourmusic[randint(0, (len(ourmusic) - 1 ))]
            randomsongBYTE = randomsong.encode('utf-8')
            send_msg(socket, randomsongBYTE)

            mixer.music.load('./music/' + randomsong)
            mixer.music.play()
            print('now playing: ' + randomsong)

            while mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
                temp = 0
            else:
                    print('music ended picking next...')

def transmitFiles(socket, files, fileBRAIN):
    Transmissions = struct.pack('i',len(files))
    send_msg(socket, Transmissions) 

    for x in files:
            filename = str(x).encode('utf-8') 
            send_msg(socket, filename)

            file = open('./music/' + x , 'rb')
            file_data = file.read()
            send_msg(socket, file_data) 

            fileBRAIN.append(str(x))
            print(x + '\n' + 'has been send transmitted successfully')
            print('')

def receiveFiles(s, fileBRAIN):            
    i = 1

    transmissionsDATA = recv_msg(s) 
    transmissionsTUP = struct.unpack('i',transmissionsDATA)
    transmissions = transmissionsTUP[0]
    print('there are ' + str(transmissions) + ' awaiting receive 
    transmissions')

    while i <= transmissions:
         BYTEfilename = recv_msg(s)
         filename = BYTEfilename.decode('utf-8')

         file = open('./music/' + filename, 'wb')
         file_data = recv_msg(s) 
         file.write(file_data)
         file.close()

         fileBRAIN.append(str(filename))
         print('transmission ' + str(i) + ' recieved')
    i = i + 1


def saveMusicList(musiclist, musicPath):
    for entry in os.listdir(musicPath):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(musicPath, entry)):
                    musiclist.append(entry)

#find elements which are not in the other list
def diff(li1, li2): 
    return (list(set(li1) - set(li2)))                 


#TCP msg proctocoll

def send_msg(sock, msg):
    # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recv_msg(sock):
     # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
     raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
     if not raw_msglen:
         return None
     msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
     # Read the message data
     return recvall(sock, msglen)

def recvall(sock, n):
     # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
     data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
           return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data
```

You can find the full code here if you need it : https://github.com/Finn1510/OpenMCS

Comment: Could you please include some of the relevant code from your project in this question?

Comment: Welcome! With a third server. Both the server and client connect to it. Otherwise, it'll be a cat and mouse game with security tools preventing the vulnerability of bypassing NAT.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work right now? If you attempt to register the server in for example your router, it should show up in the UPnP configuration in the router. You can verify if it worked there. So long as the port mapping is done right, you should have no problems with NAT at all.

Comment: @melwil Yes it works BUT the problem is that on most routers you need a premission to use UPNP for every single computer and thats simply unintuitive for the user :(

Comment: @edd a third server would be a solution but I want the programm to be accessable for everyone so nobody (including me) has to set up a server first...